# angular js bootstrap datetimepicker want to make it as required

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I want to make the angular js bootstrap datetimepicker as required field, i am using the this datepicker
https://github.com/zhaber/angular-js-bootstrap-datetimepicker I tried out with this option.

I want to validate the form, if i skip those two steps submit button should not enable.

```
<form name="addForm" novalidate>
<datetimepicker hour-step="hourStep" minute-step="minuteStep" ng-model="endDate" show-meridian="showMeridian"  date-format="dd-MMM-yyyy"                 date-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" datepicker-append-to-body="false" readonly-date="false"
            disabled-date="false" hidden-time="true" hidden-date="false" name="endDate" invalid="true" pristine="true" show-spinners="false" readonly-time="false"
            date-opened="dateOpened" show-button-bar="false" required> </datetimepicker>

<datetimepicker hour-step="hourStep" minute-step="minuteStep" ng-model="endDate" show-meridian="showMeridian"  date-format="dd-MMM-yyyy"                 date-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" datepicker-append-to-body="false" readonly-date="false"
            disabled-date="false" hidden-time="true" hidden-date="false" name="endDate" invalid="true" pristine="true" show-spinners="false" readonly-time="false"
            date-opened="dateOpened" show-button-bar="false" required> </datetimepicker>
      </div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled= addForm.startDate.$pristine && addForm.startDate.$invalid || addForm.endDate.$pristine && addForm.endDate.$invalid ng-click="addOffer('/offers')">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is in the button. Ng-disabled attribute syntax is not correct.

ng-disabled = addForm.startDate.$pristine && addForm.startDate.$invalid || addForm.endDate.$pristine && addForm.endDate.$invalid

It should be like below:=

ng-disabled = "addForm.startDate.$pristine && addForm.startDate.$invalid || addForm.endDate.$pristine && addForm.endDate.$invalid"

Missing double quote.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The library doesn't include required field. So the object is still valid with empty input

You can use `addForm.endDate.$modelValue` to check is it null in the submit button.